# simple form validation failure

Tags: forms, validation

I'm not a programmer, but I'm trying to expand an opensource Ajax contact form to include extra fields.

There are two files; [index.php](http://pastebin.com/jMq28ihy) and [send.php](http://pastebin.com/LpvaHQi3).

send.php contains simple form validation, and it includes a test to ensure the 'phone' field is non-empty.  This test fails no matter what value is entered for Phone Number.

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not an expert in PHP but you called all of your other parameters like this

```
$_POST['param name']
```

and the phone parameter like this

```
$POST['phone']
```

notice the missing

```
_
```

char. Could that be it?